# How do I animate this JS function that makes a div block/hide onclick of object?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I animate this so when the div appears and disappears expands down and retracts up? I thought maybe with css3 animations but when I add transition animations to my CSS it doesn't do anything.

```js
    function SearchToggle(){
        var off=document.getElementById('SearchContainer');
        if (off.style.display == "none") {
            off.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            off.style.display = "none";
        }        
    }
```

```css
#SearchContainer {
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        display: block;
        background-color: silver;
        color: #FFF;
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        float: left;
        width: 400px;
        min-width: 400px;
        max-width: 400px;
        height: 40px;
        min-height: 40px;
        max-height: 40px;
    }
```

```html
 <menu name="WindowMenu" id="WindowMenu" class="WindowMenu">
        <span name="WindowIcon-Span" id="WindowIcon-Span" class="WindowIcon-Span">
            <img src="ROOT.ASSETS/IMAGES/ICONS/ICON GROUP 1/FAVICON1.64.png" name="WindowIcon-PNG" id="WindowIcon-PNG" class="WindowIcon-PNG" />
        </span>

        <span name="WindowTitle" id="WindowTitle" class="WindowTitle"> PROTON CORE </span>

        <div name="WindowControl-Wrapper" id="WindowControl-Wrapper" class="WindowControlWrapper">
           <i name="SearchIcon" id="SearchIcon" class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass" onclick="SearchToggle()"></i>

           <input type="button" value="" name="WindowControl-1" id="WindowControl-1" class="WindowControl-1" onclick="window.close(true)" />
           <input type="button" value="" name="WindowControl-2" id="WindowControl-2" class="WindowControl-2" />
        </div>
    </menu>

    <form name="SearchContainer" id="SearchContainer" class="SearchContainer">

    </form>
```

I tried this instead to try an animate the height transition with CSS but it's ceased to work after changing it to height.

```
function SearchToggle(){
    var off=document.getElementById('SearchContainer');
    if (off.style.height == "0px") {
        off.style.height = "40px";
    } else {
        off.style.display = "0px";
    }        
}

#SearchContainer {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: silver;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 0px;
    //min-height: 40px;
    //max-height: 40px;

    transition: height 2s;
}
```

Comment: Where is SearchContainer element in the code?

Comment: I added it in my bad

Comment: It’s not clear from the question what css you’ve tried. Assuming you are trying to animate the appearance/disappearance of whatever element has id SearchComtainer, you need to use some other property than display alone. If you want the div to expand, e.g., you need to apply a transition to one of the width or height properties or scale or something. Or you can use opacity to fade in and out.

Comment: So I'll do the same thing but instead of display ill change the height and use css3 animation to animate the change basically? Hmm that makes sense I'm going to go fiddle with it for a min,

Comment: First, I don't know how you set the display property for SearchContainer. You may need to use `document.getElementById("SearchContainer ").classList` to add and remove classes before you check for display property .

Comment: I set it via ID (#)

Comment: also you should consider using jQuery to make your coding easier.

Comment: I just tried making it appear and disappear with the height and its not working making an edit now

Comment: ive just never really used jquery thought about it. Im still learning JS so i havent expanded into frameworks to much.

Comment: You should have two classes. one with display:none, the other is display:block. then switch between them. of course you need to add transition property.

Comment: ^^ You lost me their man. You mean both at the same time? My js changes my value of display from none to block visversa

Comment: nnoo, not at the same time, switch between them. set one class at a time and remove the second one. I will make a fiddle.

Comment: I also added in a height transition still nada my guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Here is what I think you want:

```js
var current = "up";
     function SearchToggle(){
         if(current == "up"){
            document.getElementById("WindowMenu").classList.remove("WindowMenuUp")
            document.getElementById("WindowMenu").classList.add("WindowMenuDown")
            current = "down";
         }
        else {
            document.getElementById("WindowMenu").classList.remove("WindowMenuDown")
            document.getElementById("WindowMenu").classList.add("WindowMenuUp")
            current = "up";
        }
    }
```

```css
.WindowMenuDown {
    height: 40px;
    transition: 1s;
  }
    .WindowMenuUp {
    height: 0;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  #WindowControl-Wrapper {
     overflow: auto;
  }
```

```html
<menu name="WindowMenu" id="WindowMenu" class="">
        <span name="WindowIcon-Span" id="WindowIcon-Span" class="WindowIcon-Span">
            <img src="ROOT.ASSETS/IMAGES/ICONS/ICON GROUP 1/FAVICON1.64.png" name="WindowIcon-PNG" id="WindowIcon-PNG" class="WindowIcon-PNG" />
        </span>

        <span name="WindowTitle" id="WindowTitle" class="WindowTitle"> PROTON CORE </span>

        <div name="WindowControl-Wrapper" id="WindowControl-Wrapper" class="WindowControlWrapper">
           <i name="SearchIcon" id="SearchIcon" class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>

           <input type="button" value="" name="WindowControl-1" id="WindowControl-1" class="WindowControl-1" onclick="window.close(true)" />
           <input type="button" value="" name="WindowControl-2" id="WindowControl-2" class="WindowControl-2" />
        </div>
    </menu>

    <form name="SearchContainer" id="SearchContainer" class="SearchContainer">
    <input type="button" value="Button"  onclick="SearchToggle()">
    </form>
```

If you decide to use JQuery as requested, here is a snippet:

```css
#WindowControl-Wrapper {
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <menu name="WindowMenu" id="WindowMenu" class="">
        <span name="WindowIcon-Span" id="WindowIcon-Span" class="WindowIcon-Span">
            <img src="ROOT.ASSETS/IMAGES/ICONS/ICON GROUP 1/FAVICON1.64.png" name="WindowIcon-PNG" id="WindowIcon-PNG" class="WindowIcon-PNG" />
        </span>

        <span name="WindowTitle" id="WindowTitle" class="WindowTitle"> PROTON CORE </span>

        <div name="WindowControl-Wrapper" id="WindowControl-Wrapper" class="WindowMenuUp">

           <input type="button" value="" name="WindowControl-1" id="WindowControl-1" class="WindowControl-1" onclick="window.close(true)" />
           <input type="button" value="" name="WindowControl-2" id="WindowControl-2" class="WindowControl-2" />
        </div>
    </menu>

    <form name="SearchContainer" id="SearchContainer" class="SearchContainer">
    <input type="button" value="Button" id="button">
    </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var current = "up";
        $('#button').on('click',function() {

            if(current == "up"){
                $('#WindowControl-Wrapper').show(500).slideDown(500);
                current = "down"
            }
            else{
                $('#WindowControl-Wrapper').hide(500).slideUp(500);
                current = "down"
            }

        });
    })
  //-->
  </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: You nailed it my guy! Definitely turned out to be a lot different than I thought. Would you mind sharing with me its equivalent in JQuery? You got me interested in JQuerry now. I was just tinkering with toggle to see if I could figure it out that way,

Comment: Great, I've updated the answer with jQuery equivalent. You are gonna LOVE jQuery man.

Comment: You are awesome! Above and beyond! Love from America.

Comment: Ive been messing around with it a little since you mentioned it. Im already in love with it lol. Visual makes more sense as well, which is nice.

Comment: Glad to help Dustin! Have fun coding.